# Filter dates by month in pivot table that doesn't start with the 1st of every month

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to filter dates by specific dates by month such as Jan 15 to February 15, Feb 15-March 15....etc on pivot table in excel?

My data is January 15 2017 to January 15 2018, so I like to filter it by specific dates but so far it's only letting me do the number of days which is not accurate since feb has only 28 days. thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please beef up your question as it's currently viable for closing (too broad, opinion-based answers, or not a truly objective question).  It may help to state what you have tried and the approaches which you are open to implementing.

Comment: I have tried grouping by month and day, but Jan always have overlaping data from 2017 and 2018. also tried by days/month

Comment: What @Cyril means is that you need to edit your question to include sample excel formulas / VBA code that you might have tried, along with a sample of input data and an expected outcome.

Comment: Please post images of sample raw data in your worksheet and images of what your tried so we can see what you did and how they are not returned desired results.

Comment: Since your calendar is offset to begin each month on the 15th, why not make a helper column for corporate date: =<calendar date> -14

Comment: thank you all! I did it manually with "sumifs" between dates.